# Google Docs viewerng api reference

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to show a file hosted in a public site inline on my web page using google docs by providing the following URL to an iframe.

https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url='+link+'&embedded=true

where link is the path to the file I want to show.

I am facing some issues with showing files which require user authentication.
Hence would like to see reference documentation for the API. I searched for it online was unable to find any reference documentation for the following service end point.

"https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer"

Comment: Google Docs viewerng api is not an API. For this you can do it in 2 ways: Either implement Authorization using Oauth 2.0 in your application or when requesting to access this documents that need authentication, pass your credentials along with your request if the file is owned by you in Drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Let requests originating from this Google service pass your  authentication
2. Include a *secret* parameter in the `link` to confirm that an authenticated user (of your site) is requesting the document (via **viewerng**)